# H2 sql how to set column to auto_increment

Tags: java, sql, playframework-2.0, auto-increment

i am trying to set my ID to auto_increment, but it is not doing it. i saved 2 more data into db, all are still getting 0 id. as a result i am not able to set ID as primary key.

how is it possible? can i set the field to auto_increment with JPA annotation or so?

i even tried this command which is the first attempt:

```
  alter table user alter column id int not null auto_increment;
```

no affect.

can someone help me please

thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work. Please show some code about the insert / save.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set ID as a primary key which is auto generated,then sql uniqueidentifier for it.

```
CREATE TABLE userTable(userId uniqueidentifier primary key, userName nvarchar(50)) 
         --create a table having userId as a primary key 

   INSERT INTO userTable(userId, userName ) VALUES (NEWID(), 'mohit');
   INSERT INTO userTable(userId, userName ) VALUES (NEWID(), 'doniyor');

   SELECT * FROM userTable



Result will be:

userId                                             userName

{E8E0A79D-436F-49CB-BCEC-EC9E5D69F1BB}              mohit
{21081DFA-7DBB-46AF-A160-550631160C25}              doniyor
```